# What do I need to have to travel from Estonia to Ukraine during the COVID-19 pandemic?

Tags: covid-19, eu, ukraine, estonia

There was a requirement to have a negative COVID-19 test if you visit Latvia from Estonia in January 2021.

I haven't check what is the current situation is.

P.S. useful links always welcome.

Comment: Well why don't you _check_? You expect us to check for you?

Comment: I will check it. I created this question to save all these details, and I will update it further. I hope someone will find it helpful or give me some advice. I guess it's okay to post not 100% ready question about a complex topic.

Comment: @dos4dev keep in mind that while the topic isn't complex, the requirements may change over time. So what's a good answer now might be outdated in a month's time.

Comment: You also don't meantion which **route** you will be taking.

Comment: This page is important for this trip 
https://vm.ee/en/information-countries-and-self-isolation-requirements-passengers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There was a requirement to have a negative COVID-19 test if you visit Latvia from Estonia in January 2021.

The requirement is still active for most cases, see https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/LVA/7001:

> Is a coronavirus test required?
>
> All travellers are subject to the requirement for a pre-departure negative PCR test.
> The test must be taken within 72 hours prior to arrival.
> Accepted test: molecular (PCR)
>
> Children aged 11 and under are exempted.
>
> Travellers who have already contracted the COVID-19 coronavirus will need to show a doctor's note attesting it.
>
> If a traveller is unable to show a test result (printed or on an electronic device), or a note from the doctor, the traveller will not be allowed to board the plane, train, bus, ferry, or other means of transportation. The test result or the note from the doctor must be in English, French, Russian, or in an official language of the country from which they are beginning their trip to Latvia.
>
> This requirement also applies to those arriving in Latvia in a personal vehicle.
>
> The negative COVID-19 test results must be indicated in the Covidpass.lv form, which will be checked by the State Border Guard and police officers.
>
> Persons entering Latvia to perform their job duties or travelling to or from their place of work, and employees of commercial transport companies are exempt from the COVID-19 test requirement.

Comment: _The traveller will not be allowed to board  the plane..._ even more the traveller will pay a penalty

Comment: There is another way to prove your COVID negative status - digital vaccine passport https://estonianworld.com/technology/estonia-introduces-vaccine-passport/. I am not sure if it has started to work in Latvia, Lithuania, Poland.